# You came to the right place, good job! :D

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Please help me with this code. I don't know which programming language this is. Puzzle solver, this is almost done, just this last step...

```
190 400 20 60 300 arc
[ ] 0 setdash
stroke

220 400 20 0 360 arc
[ ] 0 setdash
stroke

265 400 20 0 360 arc
[ ] 0 setdash
stroke

290 380 moveto
0 40 rlineto
stroke

290 380 moveto
25 0 rlineto
stroke

40 700 moveto
/FSFutura findfont 100 scalefont setfont
(Congrats!) show

220 600 moveto
/FSFutura findfont 50 scalefont setfont
(The) show

130 500 moveto
/FSFutura findfont 50 scalefont setfont
(answer is) show
```

Comment: You already know the answer. It is Postscript.

Comment: Now that you know the answer you can send it here: theodorseuss9@gmail.com :)

Answer (score 0):

if you save this file as a text file named text.ps, you can run it through ghostscript.

You could also use Adobe Distiller to create a pdf file.

Alternatively you can open the text.ps file in preview on a mac to see the actual answer.